# My HTML has different spacing

Tags: html

I'm really confused about this. I have same shortcode but different spacing which causes the second shortcode to fail.

```
[button link="#"]btn[/button]
[button link="#"]btn[/button]
```

They look identical but when runing on a compare tool, there's a difference in space before link.

Please see here:
http://www.diff-online.com/view/589710128ca13

How is that possible? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what character it is at [What Unicode Characters it is](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html)

You would have realized that the first one is:
U+0020 : SPACE [SP]

While second is:
U+00A0 : NO-BREAK SPACE [NBSP]

Just because they look same doesn't necessary mean they are same character.